# Is it possible to have requirement on data structure in Leon?

Tags: scala, leon

While working on rational numbers with leon, I have to add as requirement `isRational` pretty much everywhere.

For example:

```
import leon.lang._

case class Rational (n: BigInt, d: BigInt) {

  def +(that: Rational): Rational = {
    require(isRational && that.isRational)
    Rational(n * that.d + that.n * d, d * that.d)
  } ensuring { _.isRational }

  def *(that: Rational): Rational = {
    require(isRational && that.isRational)
    Rational(n * that.n, d * that.d)
  } ensuring { _.isRational }

  // ...

  def isRational = !(d == 0)
  def nonZero = n != 0

}
```

Is it possible to add a `require` statement in a class constructor to DRY this code so that it applies to all instances of the data structure? I tried adding it on the first line of the class body but it seems to have no effect...

```
case class Rational (n: BigInt, d: BigInt) {
    require(isRational) // NEW

    // ... as before ...

    def lemma(other: Rational): Rational = {
        Rational(n * other.d + other.n * d, d * other.d)
    }.ensuring{_.isRational}

    def lemmb(other: Rational): Boolean = {
        require(other.d * other.n >= 0)
        this <= (other + this)
    }.holds
}
```

This does not prevent leon from creating a `Rational(0, 0)` for example as the report suggest:

```
[  Info  ]  - Now considering 'postcondition' VC for Rational$$plus @9:16...
[  Info  ]  => VALID
[  Info  ]  - Now considering 'postcondition' VC for Rational$$times @14:16...
[  Info  ]  => VALID
[  Info  ]  - Now considering 'postcondition' VC for Rational$lemma @58:14...
[ Error  ]  => INVALID
[ Error  ] Found counter-example:
[ Error  ]   $this -> Rational(1, 0)
[ Error  ]   other -> Rational(1888, -1)
[  Info  ]  - Now considering 'postcondition' VC for Rational$lemmb @60:41...
[ Error  ]  => INVALID
[ Error  ] Found counter-example:
[ Error  ]   $this -> Rational(-974, 0)
[ Error  ]   other -> Rational(-5904, -1)
[  Info  ]  - Now considering 'precond. (call $this.<=((other + $this)))' VC for Rational$lemmb @62:5...
[ Error  ]  => INVALID
[ Error  ] Found counter-example:
[ Error  ]   $this -> Rational(-1, 0)
[ Error  ]   other -> Rational(0, -1)
[  Info  ]  - Now considering 'precond. (call other + $this)' VC for Rational$lemmb @62:14...
[ Error  ]  => INVALID
[ Error  ] Found counter-example:
[ Error  ]   $this -> Rational(1, 2)
[ Error  ]   other -> Rational(7719, 0)
[  Info  ]   ┌──────────────────────┐
[  Info  ] ╔═╡ Verification Summary ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
[  Info  ] ║ └──────────────────────┘                                                                   ║
[  Info  ] ║ Rational$$plus     postcondition                      9:16   valid     U:smt-z3      0.010 ║
[  Info  ] ║ Rational$$times    postcondition                      14:16  valid     U:smt-z3      0.012 ║
[  Info  ] ║ Rational$lemma     postcondition                      58:14  invalid   U:smt-z3      0.011 ║
[  Info  ] ║ Rational$lemmb     postcondition                      60:41  invalid   U:smt-z3      0.018 ║
[  Info  ] ║ Rational$lemmb     precond. (call $this.<=((ot...     62:5   invalid   U:smt-z3      0.015 ║
[  Info  ] ║ Rational$lemmb     precond. (call other + $this)      62:14  invalid   U:smt-z3      0.011 ║
[  Info  ] ╟┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄╢
[  Info  ] ║ total: 6      valid: 2      invalid: 4      unknown 0                                0.077 ║
[  Info  ] ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

(`this` and `other` don't always meet the constructor requirement.)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I tried out your code with require and when I do: `Rational(0, 0)` it produces: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
 at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:207)
 at test.Rational.<init>(require.scala:5)`

Comment: @AkosKrivachy Your comment made me realise that what I'm asking wasn't very clear. I'm not talking about execution the code but rather verifying that it is correct with Leon. I added some concrete example to my question that doesn't verify without redundant requirement statements everywhere.

Comment: ah, sorry, glossed over the Leon part. Sorry, can't help much there, but your question is detailed better so it should be easier for others to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difficulty with invariants can be decomposed in two problems:

### Problem 1

Given

```
case class A(v: BigInt) {
  require(v > 0)
}
```

Leon would have to inject this requirement in preconditions of all functions taking `A` as argument, so

```
def foo(a: A) = { 
  a.v
} ensuring { _ > 0 }
```

will need to become:

```
def foo(a: A) = { 
  require(a.v > 0)
  a.v
} ensuring { _ > 0 }
```

While trivial for this case, consider the following functions:

```
def foo2(as: List[A]) = { 
  require(as.nonEmpty)
  a.head.v
} ensuring { _ > 0 }
```

or

```
def foo3(as: Set[A], a: A) = { 
  as contains a
} ensuring { _ > 0 }
```

Here it is not so easy to constraint `foo2` so that the list contains only valid `A`s. Leon would have to synthesize traversal functions on ADTs so that these preconditions can be injected.

Moreover, it is impossible to specify that the `Set[A]` contains only valid `A`s as Leon lacks capabilities to traverse&constraint the set.

### Problem 2

While it would be practical to write the following function:

```
case class A(a: BigInt) {
  require(invariant)
  def invariant: Boolean = // ...
}
```

You have a chicken-and-egg issue, where `invariant` would be injected with a precondition checking `invariant` on `this`.

I believe both problems can be solved (or we can restrict the usage of these invariants), but they constitute the reasons why class invariants have you been trivially implemented yet.